Two definitions of a normal complex surface
I am looking for the definition of a "normal surface singularity". I could not find such a definition even in the book with title Normal Surface Singularities (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-031-06753-2).
By the way, I've found two definitions of a normal complex surface.

This is from Gompf and Stipsicz's book 4-manifolds and Kirby Calculus in p.246. A
singular complex manifold is normal if its singularities have codimension $\geq 2$ and all holomorphic maps defined on the smooth part can be extended.

This is from wikipedia. An algebraic variety is normal if it is normal at every point, meaning that the local ring at the point is an integrally closed domain.


Are these two definitions equivalent for (singular) complex manifolds? It seems that the second definition is common, and I couldn't find any other references using the first one as a definition. Also, is a normal surface singularity just a singularity of a normal complex surface?

The equivalence of these two is called "Serre's criterion for normality". It is Theorem II.8.2 in Hartshorne or https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031S in the Stacks project.

Another reference are Vakil's notes (July 2024 version), 13.5.23-13.5.26 and 26.3.2.

@LazzaroCampeotti Thanks. It seems that it is given in Theorem II.8.22 in Hartshorne.

You are right --- apologies for the typo.
